# How to call function with function variables but function is not defined with function variable in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

suppose there is function add

```
function add(){
  //code ......
}
```

Now I want to call `add()` with var `a` & var `b`.

I have tried with following code is it correct?

```
add(a,b);
```

is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is, please read about [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) object.

Comment: If you want what I think you want - unless you mean normal closures or what Teemu understood - is not possible (without `eval` or such) as that would be insanely insecure

Comment: You can call any function with any arguments you want. Making the function pay attention to your arguments is the tricky part.

Comment: @JanDvorak Can you please elaborate your comment, how have you understood the question? I mean if there's a missunderstanding on my side, I've to remove the missleading comment.

Comment: @teemu I think my interpretation was incorrect. I read that as wanting to override the initial values of variables inside an arbitrary function. Your interpretation makes more sense to me. I also voted to close this question as unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The answer i will give you will be yes and no

Why?

Because you have already declared this function add() without parameters going into the function, BUT you can create another function with the same name eg "function add(a,b)" that would take in parameters and possibly return the sum of the values in "function add(a,b)" to "function add()"

Or

You can just rename "function add()" to "function add(a,b)" and remodify the code to suit this method

You just have to specify which function is calling which or you will be getting null pointers exception or your code won't run altogether. Javascript is brain wrecking when it comes to errors within codes

This would be what i would do, I hope this helps :)

Comment: By null pointer exceptions (that's a java term, not a javascript term), do you mean reference errors from trying to dereference `undefined` arguments? Or, you know, you could check them first. Also, arithmetic operations on `undefined` result in `NaN`s, not exceptions.